# Replacing ActiveX with Custom Protocol Handler?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update a system that still uses ActiveX for certain things.  For example it uses this javascript to have a user login and access the internet (from our intranet)

```
var workingDirectory = "c:\\program files\\internet explorer";
var filename = "c:\\program files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe";
var arguments = referrer;
var obj = new ActiveXObject("FHS.ProcessLauncherUtility");
processId = obj.LaunchProcessReturnProcessId(domain, username, password, 
workingDirectory, filename, arguments);
```

Obviously I would prefer to do something like a custom protocol handler to deal with this and pass arguments to, however I'm not entirely that will work here since it checks the login of the user before continuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActiveX was calling a DLL which then communicated back to the ASPX page via JavaScript.   I replaced the call with a custom protocol handler to an exe (client side) which handles everything the ASPX page did within the windows application.  This made everything a lot easier.  The call to start the exe looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>    
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
        <a href="FHSProcessLaunch:freemanhealth|c:\\program files\\internet 
explorer|c:\\program files\\internet 
explorer\\iexplore.exe|http:\\google.com">Internet Login</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```